# Is it possible to keep unique index in result array using PHP PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, associative-array

I'm using the following PDO statement with the *PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE* flag to make the result array indexed by the unique row ID.

```
<?php
    $statement = $conn->prepare("
        SELECT
            unique_id, field_1, field_2, field_3
        FROM
            table
        WHERE
                field_1 = 'foo'
            AND field_2 = ?
        ORDER BY
            field_3
    ");

    if($statement->execute(array($field_2_value)))
    {
        $resultArray = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC|PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);
    }
?>
```

**$resultArray:**

```
Array
(
    [123] => Array
        (
            [field_1] => foo
            [field_2] => someVal
            [field_3] => bar
        )
    [234] => Array
        (
            [field_1] => foo
            [field_2] => someVal
            [field_3] => car
        )
    [345] => Array
        (
            [field_1] => foo
            [field_2] => someVal
            [field_3] => dog
        )
)
```

Is there a way to keep both the array indexes as they are and retain the unique row ID in the row data like this:

```
 Array
(
    [123] => Array
        (
            [unique_id] => 123
            [field_1] => foo
            [field_2] => someVal
            [field_3] => bar
        )
    [234] => Array
        (
            [unique_id] => 234
            [field_1] => foo
            [field_2] => someVal
            [field_3] => car
        )
    [345] => Array
        (
            [unique_id] => 345
            [field_1] => foo
            [field_2] => someVal
            [field_3] => dog
        )
)
```

I realise I could do this with a secondary loop but it would feel a lot cleaner if this was an option in `fetchAll()`.

Comment: Are you using a _foreach_ loop and looking for a way to utilize each _key_ in addition to each _value_?

Comment: @SamOnela Yes, I'm currently re-writing a legacy function from which the resultant array is used in many different ways throughout this codebase, and to maintain compatibility I need to retain both the key and value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it perfectly possible, as you can always add an extra field to the field list.

```
$statement = $conn->prepare("
    SELECT
        unique_id uid, unique_id, field_1, field_2, field_3
    FROM
        table
    WHERE
            field_1 = 'foo'
        AND field_2 = ?
    ORDER BY
        field_3
");
```

and have your unique_id among values.

However, I don't think it's quite necessary as you can always get an index from foreach as it mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: That is certainly a step in the right direction, thanks, but is there a way to do this keeping the key named "unique_id" instead of "uid"? I realise I could use the `as $key => $values` syntax but I'm feeding this array to some legacy code that will look for the "unique_id key" and I don't want to break it.

Comment: Did you try it? why do you think there will be anything like uid?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to keep both the array indexes as they are and retain the unique row ID in the row data[...]?

As far as I know, there is not. However, [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) supports two syntaxes:

> ```
> foreach (array_expression as $value)
>     statement
> foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
>     statement
> ```
>
> The first form loops over the array given by array_expression. On each iteration, the value of the current element is assigned to $value and the internal array pointer is advanced by one (so on the next iteration, you'll be looking at the next element).
>   **The second form will additionally assign the current element's key to the `$key` variable on each iteration.**
>   <sup>[1](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)</sup>

So use the second syntax:

```
foreach($resultArray as $key => $values) {
    //$key is contains the unique_id

    //$values contains the other fields
    //e.g. field_1, field_2, field_3
}
```

See it demonstrated in [this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/B25JAcM0mm1iuSdl).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php</sub>

Comment: Yes I realise I could use the `as $key => $values` syntax but I'm feeding this array to some legacy code that will look for the unique_id key and I don't want to break it.